# Use local Git LFS repo to check if any file changed without copying under .git

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a folder with lots of binaries. I would like to *save* the current state, make some changes and see which files are changed by `git status`. I think it is a good idea to use Git LFS, because it only keeps 3 lines for each file with size and hash information.

The problem is that `git add .` command takes a lot of time and makes a backup. Is it possible to commit only pointer files without creating LFS objects?

The commands I use:

```sh
$ git init
$ git lfs install
$ git lfs track "*"
$ echo ".gitattributes filter= diff= merge= text" >> .gitattributes
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "previous state"
$ rm -rf .git/lfs/objects/
```

I am okay with low level (plumbing) commands if there is not a porcelain solution.
In case anyone wonders how a file is saved with Git LFS, `FILENAME` is committed in the following format.

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:$(sha256sum $FILENAME | awk '{print $1;}')
size $(du -b $FILENAME | awk '{print $1;}')
```

Comment: Please provide a feedback when you are downvoting a post so that I can improve the post or elaborate the problem. I found no simple way to achieve a simple task which is version controlling of big files without unnecessarily waiting for hours (creating objects takes a lot of time, and space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving the `.git` folder, the files are shown modified in `git status`, and only way to fix the situation as for as I know is to call `git add .`, which updates the git index file. Git LFS recreates the object file if it is missing when a file is modified, so unfortunately the solution below is no different than using the commands in the question *except* this is multithreaded. On Windows, it is recommended to turn real-time protection off to avoid high CPU usage of Antimalware Service Executable.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

task() {
    REPO="$1"
    FILE="$2"
    BASE=$(cd $REPO; pwd)
    FILEPATH="$BASE/$FILE"
    SHA=$(sha256sum "$FILEPATH" | awk '{print $1;}')
    SIZE=$(du -b "$FILEPATH" | awk '{print $1;}')
    NEWFILE="$BASE.git/$FILE"
    cat > "$NEWFILE" <<-EOF
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:$SHA
size $SIZE
EOF
    echo "  Wrote out $FILE"
}

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo "Please provide the path"
    exit 2
fi
REPO="$1"

GITFILES=($(find "$REPO" -name ".git*" -exec basename {} \;))
if [[ ${#GITFILES[@]} -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "The path contains .git files. Aborting..."
    echo "Path: $REPO"
    for GITFILE in "${GITFILES[@]}"
        do echo "  $GITFILE"
    done
    exit 2
fi
FILES=($(find "$REPO" -type f -exec basename {} \;))
echo "Found ${#FILES[@]} files"

N=$(nproc --all)
echo "Number of threads: $N"

BASE=$(cd $REPO; pwd)
echo "Creating directory $BASE.git"
mkdir "$BASE.git"
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    (i=i%N); ((i++==0)) && wait
    task "$REPO" "$FILE" &
done
wait
WRITTEN=($(find "$BASE.git" -type f -exec basename {} \;))
if [[ ${#WRITTEN[@]} -ne ${#FILES[@]} ]]
then
    echo "${#WRITTEN[@]} out of ${#FILES[@]} files are written. Aborting..."
    exit 2
fi
echo "All files written"

echo "Committing the previous state"
cd "$BASE.git"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "previous state"

echo "Using Git LFS to track these files"
git lfs install
git lfs track "*"
echo ".gitattributes filter= diff= merge= text" >> .gitattributes
git add .
git commit -m "git lfs track all files"

echo "Moving .git to $REPO"
cp -r "$BASE.git/.git/" "$BASE/.git/"
cp "$BASE.git/.gitattributes" "$BASE/.gitattributes"
cd "$BASE"
git add $(git status --porcelain | awk '{print $NF;}')
echo "Erasing temporary folder $BASE.git"
rm -rf "$BASE.git"
echo DONE
```